# A better OOP way for solution

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, scala

I am implementing a functionality in `Scala` to Copy files from one `FileSystem` to another `FileSystem`.

And this is what I have implemented.

**CopyFile.scala**
Methods are empty. However, they will just call external library and will do error handling.

```scala
object CopyFiles {

  def localToHDFS(src: String, dest: String): Unit = {

  }

  def S3ToS3(src: String, dest: String): Unit = {

  }

  def localToS3(src: String, des: String): Unit = {

  }

  def HDFSToHDFS(src: String, dest: String): Unit = {

  }
}
```

**Main.scala**

```scala
import java.util.Properties

import scala.io.Source

object MainClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val propFileURI = "test.properties"
    val properties: Properties = new Properties()()
    val source = Source.fromFile( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\"+propFileURI).reader
    properties.load(source)
    val srcPath = properties.getProperty("srcPath")
    val destPath = properties.getProperty("destPath")

    if(!srcPath.contains(":") && destPath.toLowerCase().contains("hdfs")){
      CopyFiles.localToHDFS(srcPath, destPath)
    }

    if(!srcPath.toLowerCase().contains(":") && destPath.toLowerCase().contains("s3")){
      CopyFiles.localToS3(srcPath, destPath)
    }

    if(srcPath.toLowerCase().contains("s3") && destPath.toLowerCase().contains("s3")){
      CopyFiles.S3ToS3(srcPath, destPath)
    }

    if(srcPath.toLowerCase().contains("hdfs") && destPath.toLowerCase().contains("hdfs")){
      CopyFiles.HDFSToHDFS(srcPath, destPath)
    }
  }
}
```

- Is there a better OOP way to solve this?
- Would that be a good idea to write a function which returns the appropriate function based on source and destination location or based on property file to hide complexity from client code?

Comment: downvote without a explanation is not a good stackoverflow practice. if something is missing not appropriate, first point it out.

Comment: (then again, this *isn't* stack**overflow**.)

Comment: It looks like those methods shouldn't be empty. Please provide all relevant code and take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

I don't see OO design or code presented: nothing to review here.

The code presented is lacking a description of what it is to accomplish.
`main()` repeats `destPath.toLowerCase()` and `srcPath.toLowerCase()`.

```
  /** True if both parameters specified first contain required. */
  def common(a: String, b: String, required: String): Boolean = {
    a.contains(required) && b.contains(required)
  }
…
    val destLower = destPath.toLowerCase()
    if(!srcPath.contains(":") {
      if (destLower.contains("hdfs")) {
        CopyFiles.localToHDFS(srcPath, destPath)
      } else if (destLower.contains("s3")) {
        CopyFiles.localToS3(srcPath, destPath)
      }
    } else {
      val srcLower = srcPath.toLowerCase()
      if (common(srcLower, destLower, "s3")) {
        CopyFiles.S3ToS3(srcPath, destPath)
      } else if (common(srcLower, destLower, "hdfs")) {
        CopyFiles.HDFSToHDFS(srcPath, destPath)
      }
    }
```

Comment: (I *don't* know Scala.)

Answer (score 1):

## Single Responsibility

You are doing a few things in main:

- Read srcPath and destPath from the properties file
- Understand which service is responsible for each path
- Find the relevant copy function
- Call the copy function

I suggest creating a method for each of the above bullets.

## Polymorphism

You asked

> Is there a better OOP way to solve this?

I guess you mean Polymorphism as it one of the key features of OOP.

One way is to write a function that returns the relevant function. Scala support functions types very well.

Another way is creating a trait and classes that implement it (as you did the question you deleted) and a function or factory object that return the relevant class. This way is more common in OOP. Also, it is better in terms of single responsibility:`CopyFiles` do a lot of different types of copies.

## Avoid Ifs

In the question you deleted, you asked if you can rid of the ifs. when the input is the services names(and not the paths), I believe you can use pattern matching easily.